# how to get the value of Json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to get the key and value from JSON data like below.

```
{
  "data": {
    "listCard": {
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "벗꽃볼사람",
          "content": "하이",
          "createdAt": "2019-04-17T16:06:31.962772+00:00",
          "creator": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "운영자"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "벗꽃볼사람",
          "content": "하이",
          "createdAt": "2019-04-17T16:06:14.789277+00:00",
          "creator": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "운영자"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i use console.log(data.listCard) 
it shows below

```
{cards: Array(2), __typename: "ListCardResponse"}
cards: Array(2)
0: {id: "2", createdAt: "2019-04-17T16:06:31.962772+00:00", updatedAt: "2019-04-17T16:06:31.962820+00:00", title: "벗꽃볼사람", content: "하이", …}
1: {id: "1", createdAt: "2019-04-17T16:06:14.789277+00:00", updatedAt: "2019-04-17T16:06:14.789315+00:00", title: "벗꽃볼사람", content: "하이", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__typename: "ListCardResponse"
__proto__: Object
```

but i use console.log(data.listCard.cards)
it show cards is not define.

finally i want to use data.listCard.cards.map.
could you help me?

Comment: It looks like you have a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Comment: taking the information you gave, and running it in the javascript console, it runs just fine.   `var d = ...; console.log(d.data.listCard.cards);` . So I think we need more information.  Can you give us more insight as to some specifics surrouding the code.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/bham7k84/ - there's no problem with `console.log(data.listCard.cards)` . Are you sure this is the same data producing the error?

Comment: " i want to use data.listCard.cards.map" ...cards is an array and does not have any property called "map". Nor do any of the objects within it. Are you talking about the [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function? If so, sure, we could help you use it, but first you'll have to explain what you want to achieve by using it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not JSON - it's an ordinary JavaScript object. Secondly, using `object.data.listCard.cards` works perfectly:

```js
const object = {
  "data": {
    "listCard": {
      "cards": [{
          "id": "2",
          "title": "벗꽃볼사람",
          "content": "하이",
          "createdAt": "2019-04-17T16:06:31.962772+00:00",
          "creator": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "운영자"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "벗꽃볼사람",
          "content": "하이",
          "createdAt": "2019-04-17T16:06:14.789277+00:00",
          "creator": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "운영자"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

console.log(object.data.listCard.cards);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to use `.map()`. We iterate through `d.data.listCard.cards`. But you might want to consider using `forEach`.

Documentation: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Access the object `data.listCard.cards.map` or `data['listCard']['cards']`. Using bracket notation or dot notation.

Documentation: [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
let d = {
    "data": {
        "listCard": {
            "cards": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "벗꽃볼사람",
                    "content": "하이",
                    "createdAt": "2019-04-17T16:06:31.962772+00:00",
                    "creator": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "운영자"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "벗꽃볼사람",
                    "content": "하이",
                    "createdAt": "2019-04-17T16:06:14.789277+00:00",
                    "creator": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "운영자"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
// Map
// Or d['data']['listCard']['cards']
d.data.listCard.cards.map(v => {
    console.log(v)
});
// forEach
// Or d.data['listCard']['cards']
d.data.listCard.cards.forEach(v => {
    console.log(v)
});
```

I use `map` when I need to return a new array or object.

```
// Map Returns Array
let data = d.data.listCard.cards.map(v => v);
console.log(data);
```